# Google Sheets Formula to calculate Averageifs from a range of values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write have a formula to calculate the average of a number of cells with a number of given conditions.

I have cells

A1 B1 C1 D1
and
A2 B2 C2 D2

and I am trying to compute the total average of

A1/A2, B1/B2, C1/C2, D1/D2

provided that

A3:D3="Accounts*" and A2:D2 > 0

I have tried the following formulas to get this to work...

```
AVERAGEIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(D18:H18/D19:H19),D5:H5,">0", A3:D3, "Accounts*")

AVERAGEIFS({D18:H18/D19:H19},D5:H5,">0", A3:D3, "Accounts*")

AVERAGEIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(DIVIDE(D18:H18/D19:H19)),D5:H5,">0", A3:D3, "Accounts*")

AVERAGEIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(QUOTIENT(D18:H18/D19:H19)),D5:H5,">0", A3:D3, "Accounts*")
```

My most common error is: "Error Argument must be a range." Does anybody have an idea of how to go about this?

I've also tried Googling solutions on how to do this in Excel but I still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(if(isnumber(search("Accounts",A3:D3))*(A2:D2<>0),A1:D1/A2:D2)))
```

[image]

Or:

```
=average(filter(A1:D1/A2:D2,isnumber(search("Accounts",A3:D3)),A2:D2>0))
```

Comment: I never thought of nesting FILTER inside of AVERAGE- that's very clever. Thank you and nicely done!